# Show that $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\log|1-e^{i\theta}|d\theta=0$

Tags: complex-analysis

> I am asked to show $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\log|1-e^{i\theta}|d\theta=0$.

So I start with noting that $$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\log|1-e^{i\theta}|d\theta=\lim_{\epsilon->0} [\int_{-\pi}^{-\epsilon}\log|1-e^{i\theta}|d\theta + \int_{\epsilon}^{\pi}\log|1-e^{i\theta}|d\theta]=0.$$

So now I create a contour which is the unit circle except around the point z=1 we make a circle going inwards with radius $r$, so the contour looks like the unit circle with a hole around 1 (if my contour is unclear let me know please), call the whole contour $\Gamma$ and call the small arc of  circle around 1 with radius $r$ $\gamma$.

So now we use some tricks to do

$$0=\log(1-0)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\Gamma}\frac{\log(1-c)}{c}dc=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int^{2\pi -\epsilon}_\epsilon\log(1-e^{i\theta})d\theta + \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_\gamma\frac{\log(1-c)}{c}dc.$$

Now I want to estimate the real part of $|\int_\gamma\frac{\log(1-c)}{c}dc|$ in a way that when $\epsilon\to0$ that integral goes to $0$.  Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$I=\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\log|1-e^{i\theta}|d\theta=\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \log\left|e^{\frac{i\theta}{2}}\left(e^{\frac{-i\theta}{2}}-e^{\frac{i\theta}{2}}\right)\right|d\theta=\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \log\left|e^{\frac{i\theta}{2}}(-2i\sin\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)\right|d\theta$$ So

$$I=\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\log\left|2\sin\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)\right|d\theta=2\pi \log2+\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\log\left|\sin\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)\right|d\theta=\\2\pi \log2+2\int_{0}^{\pi}\log\left|\sin\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)\right|d\theta$$

So $$I=2\pi \log2+4\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\log\left|\sin\theta\right|d\theta=2\pi \log2+4\left(\frac{-\pi \log2}{2}\right)=0$$

Comment: How do you obtain $\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\log\sin\theta\, d\theta=\frac{-\pi \log2}2$?